# 10.2 error on Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, mailer

I tried hard to find an answer, but I'm not sure what the problem is. I'm wondering if there was a recent update that changed the syntax of something? Or perhaps I missed a step in the Rails tutorial? Any suggestions?

Rails version: 4.2.0

I keep getting this error when I run the test:

`bundle exec rake test:mailers`

```
1) Error:
UserMailerTest#test_account_activation:
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `edit_account_activation_url' for #<#<Class:0x00000008ace808>:0x00000008ac9240>
app/views/user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_user_mailer_account_activation_html_erb__2122098350412258357_72816220'
app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:11:in `account_activation'
test/mailers/user_mailer_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:UserMailerTest>'

1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

### Sample App

`user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb`:

```
<p>Hi <%= @user.name %>,</p>

<p>
Welcome! Click on the link below to activate your account:
</p>

<%= link_to "Activate", edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token,
                                                    email: @user.email) %>
```

`routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'sessions/new'
  resources :users
  resources :acccount_activations, only: [:edit]


  #Static pages
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get 'help' => 'static_pages#help'
  get 'about' => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup' => 'users#new'


  #get 'users/new'

  #Login/Logout actions
  get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'

end
```

`user_mailer.rb`

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'noreply@example.com'

  # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
  # with the following lookup:
  #
  #   en.user_mailer.account_activation.subject
  #
  def account_activation(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: @user.email, subject: "Account activation"
  end

  # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
  # with the following lookup:
  #
  #   en.user_mailer.password_reset.subject
  #
  def password_reset
    @user = user
    @greeting = "Hi"

    mail to: "to@example.org"
  end

end
```

`user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token
    before_save   :downcase_email
    before_create :create_activation_digest
    validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, length: {maximum: 255 },
                        format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                        uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

    has_secure_password
    validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_blank: true

    # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
    def User.digest(string)
        cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
        BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
    end

    #Returns a random token for session
    def User.new_token
        SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end

    # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
    def remember
        self.remember_token = User.new_token
        update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
    end


    # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
    def authenticated?(remember_token)
        return false if remember_digest.nil?
        BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
    end

    # Forgets a user.
    def forget
        update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
    end

    #Activates an account.
    def activate
        update_attribute(:activated, true)
        update_attribute(:activated_at, Time.zone.now)
    end

    #Sends activation email.
    def send_activation_email
        UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver.now
    end

    private
        #Converts email to all lower-case
        def downcase_email
            self.email = email.downcase
        end

        # Creates and assigns the activation token and digest
        def create_activation_digest 
            self.activation_token = User.new_token
            self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
        end

end
```

`user_mailer_test.rb`

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase

  test "account_activation" do
    user = users(:michael)
    user.activation_token = User.new_token
    mail = UserMailer.account_activation(user)
    assert_equal "Account activation", mail.subject
    assert_equal [user.email], mail.to
    assert_equal ["noreply@example.com"], mail.from
    assert_match user.name,               mail.body.encoded
    assert_match user.activation_token,   mail.body.encoded
    assert_match CGI::escape(user.email), mail.body.encoded
  end

  #test "password_reset" do
    #mail = UserMailer.password_reset
    #assert_equal "Password reset", mail.subject
    #assert_equal ["to@example.org"], mail.to
    #assert_equal ["from@example.com"], mail.from
    #assert_match "Hi", mail.body.encoded
  #end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Tricky one to track down but it was just a simple misspelling in your routes :)

routes.rb:

Change this line:

```
resources :acccount_activations, only: [:edit]
```

To the following:

```
resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
```

It's a subtle difference, but there was an extra **c** in your resource name.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just found that too. I feel stupid for even asking this question. Thanks Zoran :)

Comment: It's no problem. Trust me I've been there before :P